# Set one2many values through onchange in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How to set value for one2many field in odoo 9?
I've a one2many field login_details and its onchange function below:

```
@api.onchange('login_details')
def check_contact(self):
    return {
           'value':{'login_details': [(6,0, [])]}

            }
```

But there is no effect on GUI? Help please

Comment: There is already things in login_details field before the onchange ? Because, the function you give reset the login_details value. (6, 0 []) replaces all linked values by the ID given the list []. But in your case, the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, and make sure that the field `login_details` is not readonly.

```
@api.onchange('login_details')
def check_contact(self):
    # add your own code
    res=[(0, 0, {'first_field': value1, 
                 'second_field': value2,    
                    })] 
    self.login_details = res
```

Comment: Then make sure that the field `login_details` is not readonly

Comment: Post your code, I mean `'login_details': [(6,0, [])]}`

Answer (score 0):

Odoo cut off the onchange values changes for o2m and m2m fields as you could see at:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/models.py#L6108-L6112

You could read there a comment saying that: `At the moment, the client does not support updates on a *2many field`. This statement is false

To get it working you will need to do something like I have proposed at:

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/one2many-onchange-in-odoo-91362#answer-91400

Check and Try specifically the onchange redefined method to get it working